# Boolean variable from ViewModel can't be used as a conditional in View

Tags: javascript, asp.net, viewmodel

So I am trying to execute a script when my view loads. The problem is, whenever I use my boolean variable as a conditional, the result is always True, even if it is recognized as a False value.

More specifically:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('@Model.MyBool');
        alert('@Model.MyBool' ? "True" : "False");
    });
</script>
```

Outputs

```
False
True
```

OR

```
True
True
```

It seems that the script can recognize the correct value of the variable, but instantly forgets it when it tries to use it as a conditional. I have even tried storing it in a temporary variable, and the same thing still happens.

Is there any reason for this? I can't seem to find any information through google, and it's driving me crazy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript the conditional evals if the string `"False"` is equal to `undefined`, since it is not `undefined` it evals to `true`.

Parse the variable to a boolean or use alert this way;

```
alert('@Model.MyBool' === "True" ? "True" : "False");
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you're wrapping the variable in single quotes. Try removing the quotes.

```
alert(@Model.MyBool.ToString().ToLower() ? "True" : "False");
```

Comment: Modified the code. Since MVC renders a bool as 'False' or 'True' and those are not valid literals in Javascript, an error will be thrown. So convert the bool value to lowercase.

There may be better solutions out there.